# How can I define a function to create a variable with an especific name based on another variable? (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Example:

x = 5

list(I want to place the value of x here, in the name of this variable) = 1

P.S.: I know that I can't use parentheses in this case.

so I could do:

print(list5)

and return 1

Comment: Creating variables with dynamic names is usually not a good solution to a problem. Which problem are you trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: Just use a dictionary rather than trying to dynamically create new variables at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

That's not really true, but for almost every single case where this question is asked, the answer is either "you can't do what you want" or "what you want to do is use a list".

You mention having a variable named `list5`. So maybe what you really want is a list-of-lists or something. Have a look at the [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) tutorial to see if something there matches the problem you're trying to solve.

Here are some things you might try. These use nested comprehensions, but you don't have to do that -- you can just type out an initializer if you want.

```
list_of_lists = [[i ** 2 for i in range(j + 1, j * 2)] for j in range(5)]

dict_of_lists = { 'list' + str(j): [i ** 2 for i in range(j + 1, j * 2)]
                  for j in range(5)
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, as other comments have described, you should not be dynamically creating variables as it shouldn’t be done in general for reasons outlined by the comments. Assuming you still want to do it anyways for whatever reason here’s the code:

```
 exec “list” + str(x) + “ = 1”
```

Answer (score -1):

It is technically possible to do this by modifying the dict returned by `locals()`:

```
x = 5
locals()[f"list{x}"] = 1
print(list5)  # prints 1
```

This is needlessly complicated, though, and it's very easy to accidentally overwrite something you didn't mean to.  You're almost always going to be better off creating your own dictionary or list:

```
x = 5
my_vars = {
    f"list{x}": 1
}
print(my_vars["list5"])  # prints 1
```

Comment: [Modifying `locals()` is undefined behavior.](https://ideone.com/BQmEHv)